# problem with BREAD on Voyager (Laravel - voyager BREAD)

Tags: voyager

I clicked on:
 : Add BREAD to this table
and have a problem with this error:

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mytttweb\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\tools\bread\edit-add.blade.php)
TNX

Answer (score 0):

In vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/tools/bread/edit-add.blade.php

Change:

```
<?php $checked = (isset($dataType->generate_permissions) && $dataType->generate_permissions == 1) ? true : (isset($generate_permissions) && $generate_permissions) ? true : false; ?>
```

and

```
<?php $checked = (isset($dataType->server_side) && $dataType->server_side == 1) ? true : (isset($server_side) && $server_side) ? true : false; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php $checked = (isset($dataType->generate_permissions) && $dataType->generate_permissions == 1) ? true : ((isset($generate_permissions) && $generate_permissions) ? true : false ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php $checked = (isset($dataType->server_side) && $dataType->server_side == 1) ? true : ((isset($server_side) && $server_side) ? true : false ); ?>
```

This would fix the problem with creating BREAD.